# How can Timsort beat the O(n log n) sorting bound in some cases?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, timsort

I heard that Timsort breaks the O(n log n) bound for some cases taking advantages of data pattern. How it is possible? Can anyone explain me in detail? If it is true then Timsort will always take less comparison than quick sort because on real life data there is some pattern except data is truly random?

Can we use some kind of tricks to break O(n log n) bound on avg case for comparison sorts?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: The entropy of a random  permutation is n log n so no, we can't do better on average

Comment: @Niklas This holds only of you have no additional information about the underlying data which is rarely the case.

Comment: @pentadecagon if we analyze average case, we aggregate the runtime over all possible permutations, so this is exactly the case here

Comment: @Niklas What you say is like saying *There is no compression algorithm with an average compression ratio better than 1*.  Perfectly correct, nevertheless zip and co. are out there.  Here we are looking for the zip of sorting:  optimized for real-world data.

Comment: @pentadecagon: That's not what OP asked. OP asked for avg case and truly random data.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by **average** here.  Within the field of CS, **average** has a very precise meaning:  *The mean over all possible input sets, assuming each possible input set has the same probability.*  This definition is convenient, because it's precise and quite easy to handle, but in some cases not the most useful one, because real word data typically is different from random numbers, so an arguably better definition of **average** would be: *The mean over all real-world input sets*.  But this is not very precise and won't work in a scientific context, so you won't find this in academia.  The difference of both definitions is huge:  In real world data, you can reasonably assume that there is a fixed percentage `K1` of input sets that can be sorted in linear time by something like timsort.  For random data, the percentage `K2(n)` that can be sorted in linear time goes to zero very quickly, like `K2=Exp(-n)`, with `n` being the size of the input set.  So the precise, academic answer to you question is **No**, you cannot improve the average case.  The answer from a real-world engineer would be **Maybe**, it depends, we can try.  And they do.